# Cell formatting issues while exporting from crystal report to excel

Tags: c#, excel, linq, crystal-reports

Please find my code below.

I am trying to export crystal report to excel. When I export it to PDF, comes with tabular columns, but in excel, there is no columns or anything. I tried different formats like .Excel, .Workbook and .ExcelRecord.

How can I do cell merging? Help will be appreciated.

Thank You

```
ExportFormatType format = ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord;
                    CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExcelFormatOptions XLSFormatOptions = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExcelFormatOptions();


                    XLSFormatOptions.ExcelConstantColumnWidth = 100;
                    try
                    {

                        objAnalysis.ExportToHttpResponse(format, this.Response, false, "report.xls");
                    }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you are trying to do in your situation, but this describes the basic method of exporting to an xls file.  http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-export-excel.htm